# Errno::ENOENT in Posts#index

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a model called Post for my rails projects
the problem is i keep on getting this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in Posts#index
Showing C:/Users/Sam's/Desktop/Websites/projects/christina/cp-blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
```

My application.html.erb file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%= yield %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to fix this (I already install nodejs and restarted windows)

Comment: Is there an application.css file in your assets/stylesheets directory? I think this error is related to a missing file.

Answer (score 0):

First, `stylesheet_link_tag`, returns a stylesheet link tag for the sources specified as arguments. It will check `application.scss` or `application.css` in your `app/assets/stylsheets`. Make sure `application.css` or `application.scss` exist in that specified path.

Second, if file exist, then reinstall gem using,

```
bundle install -f
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue might have been that my scss file was named application.css.scss

Answer (score 0):

## answer

The way I fixed this was by getting rid of the require.tree in application.css and application.js